# Is it a violation of rounding your peyos if a single hair comes fully out?

Tags: payot-sideburns

Vayikra 19:27 details the prohibition of rounding your head. If a single hair would come fully plucked from the peyos area, would that be a violation of this *lav* or would it be permissible because of the amount of remaining hair in the area?

Would it change if two, three, etc. came out?

Answer (score 3):

The [Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.12.6?lang=bi) says one must leave at least 40 ([some](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Yoreh_Deah.181?lang=bi) versions say 4) hairs on each side:

> The Sages did not determine the amount [of hair] which must be left in
> the corners of our temples. We have, however, heard from our elders
> that one must leave at least forty hairs.

However, it seems he would allow plucking:

> One may remove the [hairs from] the corners [of our heads] with
> scissors. The prohibition applies only to total removal with a razor.

[Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.181.3?lang=bi) says one should not even use scissors, but it's unclear if that extends to plucking:

> He is not liable unless he uses a razor. And there are those who
> forbid scissors that shave like a razor; and their words should be
> regarded.

The [Chasam Sofer](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.139) has a lengthy analysis of the question, in which he concludes plucking is not an issue, especially when done without intent, like while combing one's peyos.